# How to cast JSONObject to integer ?

Tags: java, json, rest

i have a problem how to cast JSONObject or String to integer..

I send data once as a JSONObject

```
    @GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject sayJSONHello() {      

    JSONArray numbers = new JSONArray();

    numbers.put(1);
    numbers.put(2);
    numbers.put(3);
    numbers.put(4);             

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    try {
        result.put("numbers", numbers);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And one as a String

```
@Path("/test")
public class Hello {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayJSONHello() {      

    String myString =null;

    try 
    {           
         myString = new JSONObject().put("data", "1 2 4").toString();           
    } 

    catch (JSONException e)
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myString;
}
```

Then, i have problem how to receive this data as a Int.
I tried like this (Client):

```
  Syste m.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));  
           System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("test").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));  
  String k = service.path("rest").path("test").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);

   //  ERROR  int temp = Integer.parseInt(k);
```

Could anyone advise how to deal with it ?

Comment: Does't `k` store the full `JSON`?

Comment: What does your second println() print? You're probably getting an array/map of strings - or the full JSON as Sotirios already suggested -  rather than a single value.

Comment: Are both methods serving the same Resource URI? I think that is not possible is it?

Comment: first is Path("/hello")

Comment: second println() print -> {"data":"1 2  3 4 5 6 7 7 4"}  , and first -> {"numbers":[1,2,3,4]}  , my purpose it to "extract" from them Int.. i have 2 function, because i don't have which is better

Comment: Downvoting due to comments on my answer...  the OP clearly doesn't understand that what he wants doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable k is storing the whole JSON.  You would need to parse the JSON object first and then pull out the specific integer (I assume in the array?) that you want.

Comment: exactly, that was my plan.. JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(k) , but what now ?

Comment: What JSON parsing library are you using?  net.sf.json?

Comment: I still have a problem with function - JSONObject sayJSONHello() , how to convert JSONArray to specific integer ?

Comment: Converting an Array to a specific integer doesn't make sense.